# How to do calculations with autopostback so there's no screen flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form that does an autopostback whenever a user select a number from the dropdownlist on the web form.  The autopostback runs the code below which calculates the numbers of the form.

Screenshot:

[image]

Problem is I get a nasty flicker on the screen everytime is recalculates / autopostback.

Is there another way to code this to stop the flicker?

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int intNum1 = 0;
    int intNum2 = 0;
    int intNum3 = 0;
    int totalt = 0;

    intNum1 = int.Parse(ddlNoadults.SelectedValue);
    intNum2 = int.Parse(ddlNoseniors.SelectedValue);
    intNum3 = int.Parse(ddlNochildren.SelectedValue);

    totalt = (intNum1 * 10) + (intNum2 * 8) + (intNum3 * 6);

    tbTotal.Text = totalt.ToString();

}
```

Regards

Tea

Comment: You better do it on client side uing jquery as no server side is involved in caculations

Comment: Can jQuery calculate ASP.NET Dropdownlists?

Comment: Yes and that will be quickest solution.

Comment: Know of any jQuery tutorial that will help me learn it, so I can code this?

Comment: I have answered to do it with jquery / javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jquery/javascript. This tutorial [**how to start jquery**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) will help you.

```
$('#<%= ddlNoadults.ClientID &>', '#<%= ddlNoadults.ClientID &>', 
'#<%=ddlNoadults.ClientID &>').change(function(){
        calculate();
});

function calculate(){
    num1 = parseInt($('#<%= ddlNoadults.ClientID &>').val());
    num2 = parseInt($('#<%= ddlNoseniors.ClientID &>').val());
    num3 = parseInt($('#<%= ddlNochildren.ClientID &>').val());
    totalt = (num1 * 10) + (num2 * 8) + (num3 * 6);
    $('#<%= tbTotal.ClientID &>').val(totalt) 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     calculate();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an UpdatePanel and and AJAXing the calcs should remove or at leaset drastically reduce the flicker.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx

Comment: An update panel is a bit of overkill given it will still refresh the whole page and just update the one part. Better would be client side, or if you needed the server to do the calcs then use ajax and a web service

Comment: @RemarkLima since when does an UpdatePanel refresh the whole page?

Comment: @Ian an UpdatePanel will send a request for the entire page, the entire page will be sent back to the browser along with the ViewState and everything else (well, the ASP.NET JavaScript engine) - The script will then only take the updated part and update the page. An update panel is singuarly the most inefficient way to make ajax requests - Have a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can rely on your users having javascript enabled in their browser, this is an easy client side solution.

Just attach a function that sums the selected values to the change event of each ddl that you want to trigger the calculation...

```
$("#id-of-ddl").change(callyoursumfunctionhere);
```